# Accessing the UI controls of a WPF project from Unit Test project once the progress bar has finished loading

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, devexpress-wpf, flaui

I have a WPF application and I am trying to Automate the UI testing. I am using `FlaUI` for this. I am also using `NUnit` as the testing framework. 
My application uses `DevExpress` controls and currently I am facing an issue wherein I am not able to check the `Visibility of my progress bar` from my Unit Test application. 
Using `FlaUI` I am able to `launch` the application and get the `Window` handle but the application takes some time to set the `visibility` of the `UI elements`. 
As the UI loading is taking time and it is governed by a progress bar, I Am looking for a mechanism wherein my Test Project could check if the progress bar's visibility is `changed` and then go ahead and execute the test cases.
Here is the control's `XAML` from the WPF project

```
    <ProgressBar AutomationProperties.AutomationId="showProgress"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Height="4"
        Margin="0"
        BorderThickness="0"
        IsIndeterminate="True"
        IsTabStop="False"
        ToolTip="Contacting Server, Please Wait..."
        Visibility="{Binding IsServerActive, Converter={StaticResource MwBoolToVisibilityConverterReverse}}" />

    <views1:VoyageEditorControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
```

Here below is the code from my `Nunit` framework

```
[TestFixture(AutomationType.UIA3)]
    public class UnitTest1 : FlaUITestBase
    {


        public AutomationType AutomationType { get; }

        protected override ApplicationStartMode ApplicationStartMode => ApplicationStartMode.OncePerFixture;

        public UnitTest1(AutomationType automationType)
        {
            AutomationType = automationType;
        }

        protected override AutomationBase GetAutomation()
        {
            return UtilityMethods.GetAutomation(AutomationType);
        }

        protected override Application StartApplication()
        {
            string executableLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string projectPath = executableLocation.Replace("BP.GIS.Synergy.ShipTracker.UITests", "BP.GIS.Synergy.ShipTracker");

            string exeLocation = Path.Combine(projectPath, "BP.GIS.Synergy.ShipTracker.exe");

            var app= Application.Launch(exeLocation);
            app.WaitWhileMainHandleIsMissing();
            return app;

        }
 #region Test cases      


        [Test]
        public void getAppHandleFirst()
        {
            //  Thread.Sleep(10000);


            var mainWindow = Application.GetMainWindow(Automation);

            var elementName = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByAutomationId("AvailableViews")).AsComboBox();

            Assert.That(elementName.IsEnabled, Is.True);
            Action action = () => elementName.Click();

            RetryResults retryResult = Retry.While(action, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            bool isCompletedSuccessfully = retryResult.IsCompletedSuccessfully;

        }

        [Test]
        public void checkAppLoadProgress()
        {
            var mainWindow = Application.GetMainWindow(Automation);
            var elementName = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByAutomationId("showProgress")).AsProgressBar();

        }
```

In short, the method `getAppHandleFirst()` and others should only start executing once the progress bar is gone from the screen.